# Django: Correct way to extend a certain field in the admin change form with HTML?

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I have a model with a field based on the ImageField class.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    imagefile = models.ImageField('File', upload_to='foo/%Y/%m%/%d/')
```

Django adds - after first upload - an input tag of type file to let me change it and a link to the image to view it.

I want this original field specific (HTML) code as is (and by no means create it myself manually) but also add other HTML/JS code, say to include a thumbnail-preview or add some AJAX-stuff. I can image a few other use cases for other fields, too.

What's the correct (say: easy/unobtrusive) way to implement something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom widget. Look at `django.forms.widgets` for the code of the existing `FileInput` widget, which you can subclass and override the `render` method where necessary. You'll then just need to assign that widget for your file field in your admin form.

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you give a simple example of how to do that? I'm not getting it to work. I tried to point my FooAdmin class via "form=" to a special forms.ModelForm class with a inner Meta class referencing to the main model (as explained somewhere in the documentation). But I'm stuck with the rest.